# Eclipse import conf .xml files

Tags: xml, eclipse, configuration

I have 3 .xml files: formatter rules, code templates and clean up rules. How can I import it into Eclipse?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Window / Preferences / Java / Code Style / Clean Up / Import...

Window / Preferences / Java / Code Style / Code Templates / Import...

Window / Preferences / Java / Code Style / Formatter / Import...

Comment: Yeah, that was obvious. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way I could have a custom code-style automatically being stored in my own Eclipse bundle?
That if someone else is installing the custom Eclipse bundle that he automatically has the custom code style without manually having to import this in the Eclipse settings?

Comment: Once you import the formatter XMLs in your eclipse, it will automatically places them into the Eclipse directory. You then zip your Eclipse folder (not the workspace) and share this zip file with anyone you like. They will have the formatters in their eclipse env, and they might only have to select it from the Preferences.